# Listening to system events in order to detect http request

Tags: http, events, unix, daemon

I want to write a unix daemon for logging my http requests.

I decided to do it because I want to:

- learn something about HTTP protocol, threads (or forks), unix, etc.
- have some statistic about my internet-activity.

From theoretical point of view I see a few sub-tasks which I need to accomplish:

- start the main thread (or process) which should listen to system events.
- catch http-requests event. (e.g. I need to find some way to distinguish http-request events from other system-events)
- create a new thread (or process) to write captured http-request to the database. (I'm not sure, but I guess it's not bad idea to create a new thread (or process) for IO task in order avoid interrupting the main thread or process).

I'm not asking for complete solution or something like that, I just want to get some references/advice where can start to achieve my goal and which instrument fits better for this kind of task.

Comment: What are these "system events" you speak of? What is originating the HTTP requests?

Comment: @Celada, I'm not sure, maybe it's wrong, but I assume that when I open web-site by using browser or tools like cURL, there should be some events registred in operating system.
And maybe these events contains some information about http-requests which I'm sending (at least, I'm interesting in URL).

Comment: you should google up on web-servers. A web-server (at its most basic) is software that 'listens' to a port #.  It just scans for incoming text that meets the HTTP standard and then does what ever the received command requests (within reason and correct syntax). Those are the events in a web-serving. Good luck!

Comment: @ave You assume incorrectly. There is no such event registered with the operating system (whatever that would mean). I guess you could sniff outgoing packets (requires root or CAP_NET_ADMIN) and try to detect HTTP requests but that is complicated and error prone.

Comment: Write a HTTP proxy server then, like Squid